# POSTing JSON to REST service with Camel

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel

i have a camel route configured:

```
    <camelContext id="camel" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="demo-rest-route">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:demo.rest"/>
        <!--<setBody inheritErrorHandler="true" id="setBody2">
          <simple>name=${body}</simple>
        </setBody>-->
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" inheritErrorHandler="true" id="setHeader3">
            <constant>Content-Type: application/json;</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <toD uri="http://localhost:8181/cxf/person" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I can POST JSON manually with HttpRequester or the like without problems, but the route causes a 415-Unsupported Media Type error.
I tried to set the header, but i guess something is missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong Content-Type definiton...
It has to look like this:

```
    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" inheritErrorHandler="true" id="setHeader3">
        <constant>application/json</constant>
    </setHeader>
```

or there will be an invalid content-type.